# Amazon Blocks cURL Request?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use php cURL to fetch amazon web page but get
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable instead.  Is Amazon blocking cURL?

http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003B7Q5YY/

```
<?php

function get_html_content($url) {
    // fake user agent
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');

    $string = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $string;
}

echo get_html_content("http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003B7Q5YY");

?>
```

Comment: How do you suppose amazon could recognize curl as opposed to a browser?

Comment: That is what I am trying to find out.  Maybe Amazon looks for something that browser usually set but I didn't set in curl.  I tried the above code but it brings me to another page.

Comment: to be sure, run wireshark between your machine and amazon, capture the data, push the same stuff through curl

Comment: I used the Chrome's network inspector and put everything in the header as the browser and still doesn't work.  Lost at this point.

Comment: See previous comment - use wireshark to verify exact match

Comment: Found out that Amazon does indeed blocks your ip if you do request at fast rate.  So that was the issue.

Comment: That's very good information - post as an answer and then accept :)

Answer (score 5):

I use simple

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $offers_page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but i have another problem. if you send a lot of queries to amazon - they start send 500 page to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000WZ9NII';

$useragent = array('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/6.5.3206.48');

shuffle($useragent);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```